# Can we post actual online websites?

Tags: discussion

I have a SEO problem I can't explain, atleast not with my knowledge.

I would need to post Meta Title so people can see it. Title is "Example - Foo, Bar" yet when you do actual search on google it finds only if you type "Exa mple".

I would also like to show my site with [SeoSiteCheckup Score](https://seositecheckup.com), so I can demonstrate current state of my SEO and present my problem more clearly.

My question is what can happen if I ask a question on actual site I need a solution for?

Comment: In addition to the reasons cited by Stephen below, sites can be modified to resolve the problem or become unreachable, so requiring users to view an external link in order to view the problem is not helpful to others in the future. As a Q & A reference site, we expect questions to be applicable to others with similar issues and thus should be "self-contained" (i.e., contain enough details to answer the question without leaving the site).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We prefer when questions are asked without using the specific site as an example.  There are several reasons for that:

1. Using the site URL can be spammy.  We get a number of questions asked not in good faith.  It often appears that the question is only asked to promote the site or get links.
2. We require that questions be able to help other webmasters in the future.  Questions such as "What is wrong with this site?" won't be useful to others.  We don't allow individual site review questions.
3. Sites change over time.   Once you fix the problem on your site, your site may not illustrate the problem anymore.   We prefer that questions are self-contained and stable over time.  That way they will be more helpful to webmasters with similar problems in the future.

However, there are times in which the best way to illustrate a problem is to use your actual site as the example.   If you need to do that, go ahead and do so.  If we think it can be asked more anonymously, we will edit your question to remove your site details.

Using screenshots is a nice compromise.  They are not searchable and unlikely to be used for spam purposes.  They can often illustrate the problem showing a real site without linking to the site.   Details can be blacked out of them if desired.   If possible, take screenshots of your site, the Google searches, or your analytics to show the problem with your site.